# Is it possible to modify response headers by Tampermonkey script?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm running tampermonkey script on Twitter pages that injects CSS and makes ajax requests.

Twitter returns `content-security-policy` header that ruins script execution. As a workaround, I'm removing header with another extension for Chrome but it is inconvenient.

I wonder if I can remove response header by tampermonkey itself?

Comment: There are often workarounds, but they depend on the exact details of what you are trying to accomplish. Otherwise, the developer of Tampermonkey would have to add this capability to TM.  Or you could submit a pull-request to Violentmonkey -- which is open source.

Comment: There's an option in TM dashboard "Add Tampermonkey to the site's content security policy (CSP)"

Comment: @BrockAdams thanks for the advice.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, but that option doesn't allow you to add other domains as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't check if we can modify headers (response body i was able to modify) with this approach
but try https://github.com/jpillora/xhook/ with Tampermonkey

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Inject script
// @namespace    myproject
// @version      0.1
// @description  some description
// @author       Admin
// @match        https://somewebsite.com/*
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log(document.readyState);
    if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
        var modif2 = document.createElement("script");
        modif2.type = "text/javascript";
        modif2.src = 'https://unpkg.com/xhook@1.4.9/dist/xhook.min.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(modif2);
        console.log('--- inserted src ----');
    } else if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        var modif = document.createElement("script");
        modif.type = "text/javascript";
        modif.innerHTML = `xhook.after(function(request, response) {
  console.log('-----request accepted -----');
  console.log(response.text)
});
`;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(modif);
        console.log('--- injected JAVASCRIPT ----');
    }
}
```